# Python is killed immediately when importing cv2

Tags: python, macos, opencv, apple-m1

MacBook Air M1 w/ 16GB - Big Sur 11.2.2 - Python 3.8.8

Using conda installed through Miniforge for ARM64, I just installed OpenCV using "conda install opencv". "conda list" indicates OpenCV 4.5.1 is installed. If I simply go into python and "import cv2", I immediately get kicked out with a message: "zsh: killed python". Having a hard time diagnosing the problem. Doesn't appear to be an issue with RAM, as I have around 8GB free. Any ideas?

Edit: as of now, you need to compile opencv from source for the m1 chip. see my answer below for more details.

Comment: can try install cv on ur powershell terminal

Comment: I suggest you go with https://pypi.org/project/opencv-contrib-python/

Answer (score 0):

Conda is pain when it comes to macos. (This is my opinion)

Try using pip install

```
pip install opencv-python
```

If you want to use separate environment, I would recommend to use pipenv it is far better then conda. Install from [here](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/install/#pragmatic-installation-of-pipenv)

```sh
# create env and install opencv
pipenv install opencv-python

# activate the shell
pipenv shell
```

Comment: pip install did not work. it couldn't find a compatible version to install. conda install seems to work but actually installs an incompatible version.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that there just isn't a pre-compiled binary for the M1 chip yet. So I think the version that conda installs is incompatible with this CPU. I ended up compiling it from source and that worked. Used guide from here:

https://sayak.dev/install-opencv-m1/